# How can I globally drop docker container capabalities?

Tags: security, docker

I'd like to force all docker containers to drop particular [capabilities](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities).

But configuring docker daemon `/etc/docker/daemon.json` in this way fails:

```
{
    "cap_drop": ["SYS_CHROOT", "SETFCAP", "SETPCAP", "FOWNER"]
}
```

I've also tried to put there `cap-drop`, but it always fails with:

```
unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: the following directives don't match any configuration option: cap_drop
```

Is it even possible to force docker daemon changing this settings globally? I haven't found the list of all global settings anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The list of all possible configuration values for `/etc/docker/daemon.json` can be found at [Daemon CLI docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#on-linux).

There is clearly no way to force `cap-drop` settings for all containers using the daemon settings, so to answer my question: **You can't**.

You have to provide this settings on a per container basis.

Comment: It's really strange why this is not part of the daemon.json configuration.